# XSLT to convert XML to JSON Array

Tags: arrays, json, xml, xslt, sap-cpi

I am currently using SAP CPI to achieve this conversion. I have tried the regular XML to JSON converter available but was not able to achieve this requirement. I then set out to try and see if XSLT can help.

I am trying to convert the following XML payload:

```
<root>
    <ClientID>1</ClientID>
    <PackageID>650</PackageID>
    <SBUID>2187</SBUID>
    <CandidateID>456</CandidateID>
    <AssociateId>789</AssociateId>
    <FirstName>Meghana</FirstName>
    <MiddleName></MiddleName>
    <LastName>Rao</LastName>
    <FatherName>Satish</FatherName>
    <ContactNo>7530001169</ContactNo>
    <EmailID>dummy@sap.com</EmailID>
    <AddressHistory>
        <Address>
            <SequenceNo>0</SequenceNo>
            <AddressLine>Kharghar,navi mumbai</AddressLine>
            <City>Maharashtra-Mumbai</City>
            <State>Maharashtra</State>
            <PinCode>410210</PinCode>
            <Country>India</Country>
            <Landmark></Landmark>
            <StayFrom>01-08-2013</StayFrom>
            <StayTo>06-08-2021</StayTo>
            <IsCurrentAddress>false</IsCurrentAddress>
            <IsPermanentAddress>false</IsPermanentAddress>
            <HouseNo></HouseNo>
            <AddressType>Current</AddressType>
            <DocList>
                <listofdocs>
                    <DocumentName>abc.jpg</DocumentName>
                    <DocumentPath>base64</DocumentPath>
                </listofdocs>
            </DocList>
        </Address>
    </AddressHistory>
    <EducationList>
        <Education>
            <SequenceNo>0</SequenceNo>
            <Qualification></Qualification>
            <Degree>Under Graduate Degree</Degree>
            <CollegeName>Amrutvahini College of engineering, Sangamner (Pune University)</CollegeName>
            <Location></Location>
            <RollNumber>123123</RollNumber>
            <UniversityName>Mumbai University</UniversityName>
            <UniversityAddress></UniversityAddress>
            <PeriodFrom></PeriodFrom>
            <PeriodTo></PeriodTo>
            <YearOfPassing>2014</YearOfPassing>
            <Zipcode></Zipcode>
            <Percentage></Percentage>
            <AdditionalRemarks>10th/12th/Undergrad etc</AdditionalRemarks>
            <International>false</International>
            <Country></Country>
            <DocList>
                <listofdocs>
                    <DocumentName>abc.jpg</DocumentName>
                    <DocumentPath>base64</DocumentPath>
                </listofdocs>
            </DocList>
        </Education>
    </EducationList>
    <EmploymentList>
        <Employment>
            <SequenceNo>0</SequenceNo>
            <EmployerName>Stravis Solutions</EmployerName>
            <EmployerAddress>Bangalore</EmployerAddress>
            <EmployerContactNo></EmployerContactNo>
            <Designation>SDE</Designation>
            <EmployeeID>asdas</EmployeeID>
            <FixedSalary>0</FixedSalary>
            <IsCurrentEmployment>false</IsCurrentEmployment>
            <RelievingDate>15-10-2021</RelievingDate>
            <State></State>
            <City></City>
            <Zipcode></Zipcode>
            <International>false</International>
            <Country></Country>
            <PFNumber></PFNumber>
            <UANNumber></UANNumber>
            <DocList>
                <listofdocs>
                    <DocumentName>abc.jpg</DocumentName>
                    <DocumentPath>base64</DocumentPath>
                </listofdocs>
            </DocList>
            <DateOfJoining>18-03-2015</DateOfJoining>
        </Employment>
        <Employment>
            <SequenceNo>0</SequenceNo>
            <EmployerName>Stravis Solutions</EmployerName>
            <EmployerAddress>Bangalore</EmployerAddress>
            <EmployerContactNo></EmployerContactNo>
            <Designation>SDE</Designation>
            <EmployeeID>asdas</EmployeeID>
            <FixedSalary>0</FixedSalary>
            <IsCurrentEmployment>false</IsCurrentEmployment>
            <RelievingDate>15-10-2021</RelievingDate>
            <International>false</International>
            <Country></Country>
            <PFNumber></PFNumber>
            <UANNumber></UANNumber>
            <DocList>
                <listofdocs>
                    <DocumentName>abc.jpg</DocumentName>
                    <DocumentPath>base64</DocumentPath>
                </listofdocs>
            </DocList>
            <DateOfJoining>18-03-2015</DateOfJoining>
        </Employment>
    </EmploymentList>
    <AddressReferencesList>
        <ListofReferences>
            <OrganizationName>Com 1</OrganizationName>
            <AdditionalRemarks></AdditionalRemarks>
            <NameOfReferee>Ref1</NameOfReferee>
            <RefereeOccupation>SDE</RefereeOccupation>
            <RefereePhoneNumber>123456</RefereePhoneNumber>
            <RefereeEmailAddress>Ref1@com1.com</RefereeEmailAddress>
        </ListofReferences>
        <ListofReferences>
            <OrganizationName>Com 1</OrganizationName>
            <AdditionalRemarks></AdditionalRemarks>
            <NameOfReferee>Ref1</NameOfReferee>
            <RefereeOccupation>SDE</RefereeOccupation>
            <RefereePhoneNumber>123456</RefereePhoneNumber>
            <RefereeEmailAddress>Ref1@com1.com</RefereeEmailAddress>
        </ListofReferences>
    </AddressReferencesList>
    <DOB>03-08-2021</DOB>
    <DLDetails>
        <DOB>03-08-2021</DOB>
        <ApplicantName>Test</ApplicantName>
        <FatherName>Test</FatherName>
        <dl_remarks></dl_remarks>
        <UniqueIDCode>1231231</UniqueIDCode>
        <DocList>
            <listofdocs>
                <DocumentName>abc.jpg</DocumentName>
                <DocumentPath>base64</DocumentPath>
            </listofdocs>
        </DocList>
    </DLDetails>
    <PanDetails>
        <DOB>03-08-2021</DOB>
        <ApplicantName>Sunil Kumar  Yadav</ApplicantName>
        <FatherName>Sunil</FatherName>
        <pan_remarks></pan_remarks>
        <UniqueIDCode>23123131</UniqueIDCode>
        <DocList>
            <listofdocs>
                <DocumentName>abc.jpg</DocumentName>
                <DocumentPath>base64</DocumentPath>
            </listofdocs>
        </DocList>
    </PanDetails>
    <PVWDetails>
        <AddressList>
            <Address>
                <SequenceNo>0</SequenceNo>
                <AddressLine>Kharghar,navi mumbai</AddressLine>
                <City>Maharashtra-Mumbai</City>
                <State>Maharashtra</State>
                <PinCode>410210</PinCode>
                <Country>India</Country>
                <Landmark></Landmark>
                <StayFrom>01-08-2013</StayFrom>
                <StayTo>06-08-2021</StayTo>
                <IsCurrentAddress>false</IsCurrentAddress>
                <IsPermanentAddress>false</IsPermanentAddress>
                <HouseNo>Sai shradha CHS.Sector-11,</HouseNo>
                <AddressType>Current</AddressType>
                <DocList>
                    <listofdocs>
                        <DocumentName>abc.jpg</DocumentName>
                        <DocumentPath>base64</DocumentPath>
                    </listofdocs>
                </DocList>
            </Address>
        </AddressList>
        <DOB>03-08-2021</DOB>
        <FatherName>Sunil</FatherName>
        <ApplicantName>Sunil Kumar  Yadav</ApplicantName>
    </PVWDetails>
    <CreditDetail>
        <ApplicantName>Test</ApplicantName>
        <DOB>03-08-2021</DOB>
        <FatherName>Test</FatherName>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <UniqueIDCode>Pan Number</UniqueIDCode>
        <EmailID>asda@gmail.com</EmailID>
        <DocList>
            <listofdocs>
                <DocumentName>abc.jpg</DocumentName>
                <DocumentPath>base64</DocumentPath>
            </listofdocs>
        </DocList>
    </CreditDetail>
    <DrugTestPanelCheck>
        <DrugTestPanel>DrugTestPanel5</DrugTestPanel>
        <ApplicantName>Test Candidate</ApplicantName>
    </DrugTestPanelCheck>
    <GDCDetails>
        <ApplicantName>Sunil Kumar  Yadav</ApplicantName>
        <DOB>03-08-2021</DOB>
        <FatherName>Sunil</FatherName>
    </GDCDetails>
    <PassportCheckDetails>
        <NameInPassport>Sunil Kumar  Yadav</NameInPassport>
        <PassportNo>1231231</PassportNo>
        <MachineReadableZone></MachineReadableZone>
        <CandidateFirstName>Sunil</CandidateFirstName>
        <CandidateLastName>Yadav</CandidateLastName>
        <DOB>03-08-2021</DOB>
        <FatherName>Sunil</FatherName>
        <DocList>
            <listofdocs>
                <DocumentName>abc.jpg</DocumentName>
                <DocumentPath>base64</DocumentPath>
            </listofdocs>
        </DocList>
    </PassportCheckDetails>
</root>
```

To the below JSON payload, which as you can see has multiple array elements for even single payloads:

```
{
    "ClientID": "1",
    "PackageID": "650",
    "SBUID": "2187",
    "CandidateID": "456",
    "AssociateId": "789",
    "FirstName": "Meghana",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "Rao",
    "FatherName": "Satish",
    "ContactNo": "7530001169",
    "EmailID": "dummy@sap.com",
    "AddressHistory": {
        "Address": [
            {
                "SequenceNo": "0",
                "AddressLine": "Kharghar,navi mumbai",
                "City": "Maharashtra-Mumbai",
                "State": "Maharashtra",
                "PinCode": "410210",
                "Country": "India",
                "Landmark": "",
                "StayFrom": "01-08-2013",
                "StayTo": "06-08-2021",
                "IsCurrentAddress": false,
                "IsPermanentAddress": false,
                "HouseNo": "",
                "AddressType": "Current",
                "DocList": {
                    "listofdocs": [
                        {
                                    "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
                            "DocumentPath": "base64"                        
                         }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "EducationList": {
        "Education": [
            {
                "SequenceNo": "0",
                "Qualification": "",
                "Degree": "Under Graduate Degree",
                "CollegeName": "Amrutvahini College of engineering, Sangamner (Pune University)",
                "Location": "",
                "RollNumber": "123123",
                "UniversityName": "Mumbai University",
                "UniversityAddress": "",
                "PeriodFrom": "",
                "PeriodTo": "",
                "YearOfPassing": "2014",
                "Zipcode": "",
                "Percentage": "",
                "AdditionalRemarks": "10th/12th/Undergrad etc",
                "International": false,
                "Country": "",
                "DocList": {
                    "listofdocs": [
                        {
                                    "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
                            "DocumentPath": "base64"                        
                         }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "EmploymentList": {
        "Employment": [
            {
                "SequenceNo": "0",
                "EmployerName": "Stravis Solutions",
                "EmployerAddress": "Bangalore",
                "EmployerContactNo": "",
                "Designation": "SDE",
                "EmployeeID": "asdas",
                "FixedSalary": "0",
                "IsCurrentEmployment": false,
                "RelievingDate": "15-10-2021",
                "Zipcode": "",
                "International": false,
                "Country": "",
                "PFNumber": "",
                "UANNumber": "",
                "DocList": {
                    "listofdocs": [
                        {
                                    "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
                            "DocumentPath": "base64"                        
                         }
                    ]
                },
                "DateOfJoining": "18-03-2015"
            },
            {
                "SequenceNo": "0",
                "EmployerName": "Stravis Solutions",
                "EmployerAddress": "Bangalore",
                "EmployerContactNo": "",
                "Designation": "SDE",
                "EmployeeID": "asdas",
                "FixedSalary": "0",
                "IsCurrentEmployment": false,
                "RelievingDate": "15-10-2021",
                "Zipcode": "",
                "International": false,
                "Country": "",
                "PFNumber": "",
                "UANNumber": "",
                "DocList": {
                    "listofdocs": [
                        {
                                    "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
                            "DocumentPath": "base64"                        
                         }
                    ]
                },
                "DateOfJoining": "18-03-2015"
            }
        ]
    },
    "AddressReferencesList": {
        "ListofReferences": [
            {
                "OrganizationName": "Com 1",
                "AdditionalRemarks": "",
                "NameOfReferee": "Ref1",
                "RefereeOccupation": "SDE",
                "RefereePhoneNumber": "123456",
                "RefereeEmailAddress": "Ref1@com1.com"
            },
            {
                "OrganizationName": "Com 1",
                "AdditionalRemarks": "",
                "NameOfReferee": "Ref2",
                "RefereeOccupation": "SDE",
                "RefereePhoneNumber": "123456",
                "RefereeEmailAddress": "Ref1@com1.com"
            }
        ]
    },
    "DOB": "03-08-2021",
    "DLDetails": {
        "DOB": "03-08-2021",
        "ApplicantName": "Test",
        "FatherName": "Test",
        "UniqueIDCode": "1231231",
        "DocList": {
            "listofdocs": [
                  {
                                    "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
                            "DocumentPath": "base64"                        
                         }
            ]
        }
    },
    "PanDetails": {
        "DOB": "03-08-2021",
        "ApplicantName": "Sunil Kumar  Yadav",
        "FatherName": "Sunil",
        "UniqueIDCode": "23123131",
        "DocList": {
            "listofdocs": [
                {
                                    "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
                            "DocumentPath": "base64"                        
                   }
            ]
        }
    },
    "PVWDetails": {
        "AddressList": {
            "Address": [
                {
                    "SequenceNo": "0",
                    "AddressLine": "Kharghar,navi mumbai",
                    "City": "Maharashtra-Mumbai",
                    "State": "Maharashtra",
                    "PinCode": "410210",
                    "Country": "India",
                    "Landmark": "",
                    "StayFrom": "01-08-2013",
                    "StayTo": "06-08-2021",
                    "IsCurrentAddress": false,
                    "IsPermanentAddress": false,
                    "HouseNo": "Sai shradha CHS.Sector-11,",
                    "AddressType": "Current",
                    "DocList": {
                        "listofdocs": [
                            {
                                    "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
                            "DocumentPath": "base64"                        
                         }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "DOB": "03-08-2021",
        "FatherName": "Sunil",
        "ApplicantName": "Sunil Kumar  Yadav"
    },
    "CreditDetail": {
        "ApplicantName": "Test",
        "DOB": "03-08-2021",
        "FatherName": "Test",
        "Gender": "Male",
        "UniqueIDCode": "Pan Number",
        "EmailID": "asda@gmail.com",
        "DocList": {
            "listofdocs": [
                {
                                    "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
                            "DocumentPath": "base64"                        
                         }

            ]
        }
    },
    "PassportCheckDetails": {
        "NameInPassport": "Sunil Kumar  Yadav",
        "PassportNo": "1231231",
        "MachineReadableZone": "",
        "CandidateFirstName": "Sunil",
        "CandidateLastName": "Yadav",
        "DOB": "03-08-2021",
        "FatherName": "Sunil",
        "DocList": {
            "listofdocs": [
                {
                                    "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
                            "DocumentPath": "base64"                        
                         }

            ]
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is an array created for every part of the data. How can I achieve this with XSLT?

Whatever code i have tried with so far, the converted JSON has not had any arrays barring cases where there are multiple records under a root.

I have tried variations of the following code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="http://use your namespace">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/ns0:Account_Resp">{
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/> }
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- Object or Element Property-->
    <xsl:template match="*">
    
        "<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
        
    
    </xsl:template>
    
    
    <!-- Array Element -->
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="ArrayElement">
        <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    
    <!-- Object Properties -->
    <xsl:template name="Properties">
        <xsl:variable name="childName" select="name(*[1])"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(*|@*)">"<xsl:value-of select="."/>"</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="count(*[name()=$childName]) > 1">{ "<xsl:value-of select="$childName"/>" :[<xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="ArrayElement"/>] }</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>{
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    }</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    
    
    <!-- Attribute Property -->
    <xsl:template `enter code here`match="@*">"<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="."/>",
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

And received the following output - in which you can see that for single payloads, an array is not getting created:

```
{
    "ClientID" : "1",
    "PackageID" : "650",
    "SBUID" : "2187",
    "CandidateID" : "456",
    "AssociateId" : "789",
    "FirstName" : "Meghana",
    "MiddleName" : "",
    "LastName" : "Rao",
    "FatherName" : "Satish",
    "ContactNo" : "7530001169",
    "EmailID" : "dummy@sap.com",

    "AddressHistory" : { "Address" :[{
    "SequenceNo" : "0",
    "AddressLine" : "Kharghar,navi mumbai",
    "City" : "Maharashtra-Mumbai",
    "State" : "Maharashtra",
    "PinCode" : "410210",
    "Country" : "India",
    "Landmark" : "",
    "StayFrom" : "01-08-2013",
    "StayTo" : "06-08-2021",
    "IsCurrentAddress" : "false",
    "IsPermanentAddress" : "false",
    "HouseNo" : "",
    "AddressType" : "Current",
    "DocList" : { "listofdocs" :[{
    "DocumentName" : "abc.jpg",
    "DocumentPath" : "base64"
}] }
},{
    "SequenceNo" : "1",
    "AddressLine" : "Kharghar,navi mumbai",
    "City" : "Maharashtra-Mumbai",
    "State" : "Maharashtra",
    "PinCode" : "410210",
    "Country" : "India",
    "Landmark" : "",
    "StayFrom" : "01-08-2013",
    "StayTo" : "06-08-2021",
    "IsCurrentAddress" : "false",
    "IsPermanentAddress" : "false",
    "HouseNo" : "",
    "AddressType" : "Current",
    "DocList" : { "listofdocs" :[{
    "DocumentName" : "def.jpg",
    "DocumentPath" : "base64"
}] }
}] },

    "EducationList" : {
    "Education" : {
    "SequenceNo" : "0",
    "Qualification" : "",
    "Degree" : "Under Graduate Degree",
    "CollegeName" : "Amrutvahini College of engineering, Sangamner (Pune University)",
    "Location" : "",
    "RollNumber" : "123123",
    "UniversityName" : "Mumbai University",
    "UniversityAddress" : "",
    "PeriodFrom" : "",
    "PeriodTo" : "",
    "YearOfPassing" : "2014",
    "Percentage" : "",
    "AdditionalRemarks" : "10th/12th/Undergrad etc",
    "International" : "false",
    "Country" : "",
    "DocList" : { "listofdocs" :[{
    "DocumentName" : "def.jpg",
    "DocumentPath" : "base64"
}] }
}
},
    "EmploymentList" : { "Employment" :[{
    "SequenceNo" : "0",
    "EmployerName" : "Stravis Solutions",
    "EmployerAddress" : "Bangalore",
    "EmployerContactNo" : "",
    "Designation" : "SDE",
    "EmployeeID" : "asdas",
    "FixedSalary" : "0",
    "IsCurrentEmployment" : "false",
    "RelievingDate" : "15-10-2021",
    "Zipcode" : "",
    "International" : "false",
    "Country" : "",
    "PFNumber" : "",
    "UANNumber" : "",
    "DocList" : {
    "listofdocs" : {
    "DocumentName" : "abc.jpg",
    "DocumentPath" : "base64"
}
},
    "DateOfJoining" : "18-03-2015"
},{
    "SequenceNo" : "1",
    "EmployerName" : "Stravis Solutions",
    "EmployerAddress" : "Bangalore",
    "EmployerContactNo" : "",
    "Designation" : "SDE",
    "EmployeeID" : "asdas",
    "FixedSalary" : "0",
    "IsCurrentEmployment" : "false",
    "RelievingDate" : "15-10-2021",
    "Zipcode" : "",
    "International" : "false",
    "Country" : "",
    "PFNumber" : "",
    "UANNumber" : "",
    "DocList" : {
    "listofdocs" : {
    "DocumentName" : "def.jpg",
    "DocumentPath" : "base64"
}
},
    "DateOfJoining" : "18-03-2015"
}] },

    "AddressReferencesList" : { "ListofReferences" :[{
    "OrganizationName" : "Com 1",
    "AdditionalRemarks" : "",
    "NameOfReferee" : "Ref1",
    "RefereeOccupation" : "SDE",
    "RefereePhoneNumber" : "123456",
    "RefereeEmailAddress" : "Ref1@com1.com"
},{
    "OrganizationName" : "Com 1",
    "AdditionalRemarks" : "",
    "NameOfReferee" : "Ref2",
    "RefereeOccupation" : "SDE",
    "RefereePhoneNumber" : "123456",
    "RefereeEmailAddress" : "Ref1@com1.com"
}] },
    "DOB" : "03-08-2021",
    "DLDetails" : {
    "DOB" : "03-08-2021",
    "ApplicantName" : "Test",
    "FatherName" : "Test",
    "UniqueIDCode" : "1231231",
    "DocList" : {
    "listofdocs" : {
    "DocumentName" : "abc.jpg",
    "DocumentPath" : "base64"
}
}
},
    "PanDetails" : {
    "DOB" : "03-08-2021",
    "ApplicantName" : "Sunil Kumar  Yadav",
    "FatherName" : "Sunil",
    "UniqueIDCode" : "23123131",
    "DocList" : {
    "listofdocs" : {
    "DocumentName" : "abc.jpg",
    "DocumentPath" : "base64"
}
}
},
    "PVWDetails" : {
    "AddressList" : {
    "Address" : {
    "SequenceNo" : "0",
    "AddressLine" : "Kharghar,navi mumbai",
    "City" : "Maharashtra-Mumbai",
    "State" : "Maharashtra",
    "PinCode" : "410210",
    "Country" : "India",
    "Landmark" : "",
    "StayFrom" : "01-08-2013",
    "StayTo" : "06-08-2021",
    "IsCurrentAddress" : "false",
    "IsPermanentAddress" : "false",
    "HouseNo" : "Sai shradha CHS.Sector-11,",
    "AddressType" : "Current"
}
},
    "DOB" : "03-08-2021",
    "FatherName" : "Sunil",
    "ApplicantName" : "Sunil Kumar  Yadav"
},
    "CreditDetail" : {
    "ApplicantName" : "Test",
    "DOB" : "03-08-2021",
    "FatherName" : "Test",
    "Gender" : "Male",
    "UniqueIDCode" : "Pan Number",
    "EmailID" : "asda@gmail.com",
    "DocList" : {
    "listofdocs" : {
    "DocumentName" : "abc.jpg",
    "DocumentPath" : "base64"
}
}
},        "DrugTestPanelCheck" : {
    "DrugTestPanel" : "DrugTestPanel5",
    "ApplicantName" : "Test Candidate"
},
    "GDCDetails" : {
    "ApplicantName" : "Sunil Kumar  Yadav",
    "DOB" : "03-08-2021",
    "FatherName" : "Sunil"
},
    "PassportCheckDetails" : {
    "NameInPassport" : "Sunil Kumar  Yadav",
    "PassportNo" : "1231231",
    "MachineReadableZone" : "",
    "CandidateFirstName" : "Sunil",
    "CandidateLastName" : "Yadav",
    "DOB" : "03-08-2021",
    "FatherName" : "Sunil",
    "DocList" : {
    "listofdocs" : {
    "DocumentName" : "abc.jpg",
    "DocumentPath" : "base64"
}
}
}
}
```

Really need some help on this.
Thanks

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: Hi Yitzhak, thank you for pointing this out. I have added the code i have tried this with so far.

Comment: What about item #4?

Comment: My apologies, I am new to XSLT so I may have missed this. Is it not present in the XSLT code?

Comment: For example, Saxon XSLT processor is conformant with XSLT 4.0, 30, etc. standards. Though, an XSLT file itself still could be 1.0. It is better to use XSLT processor that is conformant with 4.0 and 3.0 They natively support JSON

Answer (score 1):

In order to determine which XML elements can occur with cardinality 0..*, you look only at the actual cardinality in the payload by testing whether `count(*[name()=$childName]) > 1`. By this, you miss the fact that the `<EducationList>` is *allowed* to contain more than one `<Education>` (even if it contains only one in this particular payload instance).

A clean solution would require you to look at the XML schema (in the WSDL document, probably). But in this case, the following heuristics might suffice: If an element name ends with `List`, it contains children with cardinality 0..*. Therefore, replace the test `count(*[name()=$childName]) > 1` with

```
substring(name(), string-length(name()) - 3, 4) = 'List'
```

Answer (score 0):

With the YAML processor [mikefarah/yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/), you can convert XML to JSON and make some custom adoptions to the conversion:

```bash
yq --input-format xml --output-format json '
with(.root;
     .AddressHistory.Address                 |= select(type == "!!map") |= [.] |
     .EducationList.Education                |= select(type == "!!map") |= [.] |
     .EmploymentList.Employment              |= select(type == "!!map") |= [.] |
     .AddressReferencesList.ListofReferences |= select(type == "!!map") |= [.] |
     .PVWDetails.AddressList.Address         |= select(type == "!!map") |= [.]
    )
   ' input.xml
```

For given paths the update operator `|=` wraps an object (`select(type == "!!map")`) into an array (`[.]`).
Add all elements that should be an array to the code.

---

With [kislyuk/xq](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/#xml-support), you can solve it this way:

```bash
ARRAY_PATHS='
[
  "root.AddressHistory.Address",
  "root.EducationList.Education",
  "root.EmploymentList.Employment",
  "root.AddressReferencesList.ListofReferences",
  "root.PVWDetails.AddressList.Address"
]
'

xq --argjson paths "$ARRAY_PATHS" '
  . as $input
  | reduce ($paths
            | map(split(".")                                              # split given paths by "."
                  | . as $p
                  | select($input | getpath($p) | type == "object")))[]   # process only objects at the given paths (ignore arrays)
           as $path
           (.; setpath($path; [getpath($path)]))                          # wrap objects at the given paths in an array
 ' input.xml
```

All given paths are checked if the value is an object: `select($input | getpath($p) | type == "object")`.
Objects are wrapped into an array `setpath($path; [getpath($path)])`.
This solution is more generic and failsafe, if a given path is missing in the input.

---

**Output (both versions)**

```json
{
  "root": {
    "ClientID": "1",
    "PackageID": "650",
    "SBUID": "2187",
    "CandidateID": "456",
    "AssociateId": "789",
    "FirstName": "Meghana",
    "MiddleName": null,
    "LastName": "Rao",
    "FatherName": "Satish",
    "ContactNo": "7530001169",
    "EmailID": "dummy@sap.com",
    "AddressHistory": {
      "Address": [
        {
          "SequenceNo": "0",
          "AddressLine": "Kharghar,navi mumbai",
          "City": "Maharashtra-Mumbai",
          "State": "Maharashtra",
          "PinCode": "410210",
          "Country": "India",
          "Landmark": null,
          "StayFrom": "01-08-2013",
          "StayTo": "06-08-2021",
          "IsCurrentAddress": "false",
          "IsPermanentAddress": "false",
          "HouseNo": null,
          "AddressType": "Current",
          "DocList": {
            "listofdocs": {
              "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
              "DocumentPath": "base64"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "EducationList": {
      "Education": [
        {
          "SequenceNo": "0",
          "Qualification": null,
          "Degree": "Under Graduate Degree",
          "CollegeName": "Amrutvahini College of engineering, Sangamner (Pune University)",
          "Location": null,
          "RollNumber": "123123",
          "UniversityName": "Mumbai University",
          "UniversityAddress": null,
          "PeriodFrom": null,
          "PeriodTo": null,
          "YearOfPassing": "2014",
          "Zipcode": null,
          "Percentage": null,
          "AdditionalRemarks": "10th/12th/Undergrad etc",
          "International": "false",
          "Country": null,
          "DocList": {
            "listofdocs": {
              "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
              "DocumentPath": "base64"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "EmploymentList": {
      "Employment": [
        {
          "SequenceNo": "0",
          "EmployerName": "Stravis Solutions",
          "EmployerAddress": "Bangalore",
          "EmployerContactNo": null,
          "Designation": "SDE",
          "EmployeeID": "asdas",
          "FixedSalary": "0",
          "IsCurrentEmployment": "false",
          "RelievingDate": "15-10-2021",
          "State": null,
          "City": null,
          "Zipcode": null,
          "International": "false",
          "Country": null,
          "PFNumber": null,
          "UANNumber": null,
          "DocList": {
            "listofdocs": {
              "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
              "DocumentPath": "base64"
            }
          },
          "DateOfJoining": "18-03-2015"
        },
        {
          "SequenceNo": "0",
          "EmployerName": "Stravis Solutions",
          "EmployerAddress": "Bangalore",
          "EmployerContactNo": null,
          "Designation": "SDE",
          "EmployeeID": "asdas",
          "FixedSalary": "0",
          "IsCurrentEmployment": "false",
          "RelievingDate": "15-10-2021",
          "International": "false",
          "Country": null,
          "PFNumber": null,
          "UANNumber": null,
          "DocList": {
            "listofdocs": {
              "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
              "DocumentPath": "base64"
            }
          },
          "DateOfJoining": "18-03-2015"
        }
      ]
    },
    "AddressReferencesList": {
      "ListofReferences": [
        {
          "OrganizationName": "Com 1",
          "AdditionalRemarks": null,
          "NameOfReferee": "Ref1",
          "RefereeOccupation": "SDE",
          "RefereePhoneNumber": "123456",
          "RefereeEmailAddress": "Ref1@com1.com"
        },
        {
          "OrganizationName": "Com 1",
          "AdditionalRemarks": null,
          "NameOfReferee": "Ref1",
          "RefereeOccupation": "SDE",
          "RefereePhoneNumber": "123456",
          "RefereeEmailAddress": "Ref1@com1.com"
        }
      ]
    },
    "DOB": "03-08-2021",
    "DLDetails": {
      "DOB": "03-08-2021",
      "ApplicantName": "Test",
      "FatherName": "Test",
      "dl_remarks": null,
      "UniqueIDCode": "1231231",
      "DocList": {
        "listofdocs": {
          "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
          "DocumentPath": "base64"
        }
      }
    },
    "PanDetails": {
      "DOB": "03-08-2021",
      "ApplicantName": "Sunil Kumar  Yadav",
      "FatherName": "Sunil",
      "pan_remarks": null,
      "UniqueIDCode": "23123131",
      "DocList": {
        "listofdocs": {
          "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
          "DocumentPath": "base64"
        }
      }
    },
    "PVWDetails": {
      "AddressList": {
        "Address": [
          {
            "SequenceNo": "0",
            "AddressLine": "Kharghar,navi mumbai",
            "City": "Maharashtra-Mumbai",
            "State": "Maharashtra",
            "PinCode": "410210",
            "Country": "India",
            "Landmark": null,
            "StayFrom": "01-08-2013",
            "StayTo": "06-08-2021",
            "IsCurrentAddress": "false",
            "IsPermanentAddress": "false",
            "HouseNo": "Sai shradha CHS.Sector-11,",
            "AddressType": "Current",
            "DocList": {
              "listofdocs": {
                "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
                "DocumentPath": "base64"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "DOB": "03-08-2021",
      "FatherName": "Sunil",
      "ApplicantName": "Sunil Kumar  Yadav"
    },
    "CreditDetail": {
      "ApplicantName": "Test",
      "DOB": "03-08-2021",
      "FatherName": "Test",
      "Gender": "Male",
      "UniqueIDCode": "Pan Number",
      "EmailID": "asda@gmail.com",
      "DocList": {
        "listofdocs": {
          "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
          "DocumentPath": "base64"
        }
      }
    },
    "DrugTestPanelCheck": {
      "DrugTestPanel": "DrugTestPanel5",
      "ApplicantName": "Test Candidate"
    },
    "GDCDetails": {
      "ApplicantName": "Sunil Kumar  Yadav",
      "DOB": "03-08-2021",
      "FatherName": "Sunil"
    },
    "PassportCheckDetails": {
      "NameInPassport": "Sunil Kumar  Yadav",
      "PassportNo": "1231231",
      "MachineReadableZone": null,
      "CandidateFirstName": "Sunil",
      "CandidateLastName": "Yadav",
      "DOB": "03-08-2021",
      "FatherName": "Sunil",
      "DocList": {
        "listofdocs": {
          "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
          "DocumentPath": "base64"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to wrap all child elements in an array - even if there is only one child element.

Comment: I changed the code according to your wishes

Answer (score 0):

The standard `xml-to-json` XSLT 3.0 function **can** meet your requirement. The complexity lies in establishing the transform rules for when to use JSON maps and arrays.

I inferred the transform rules from the supplied input XML and output JSON. These rules may need adjustment to cover cases not tested by your sample. Here's the main `xsl:template` instruction:

```
<xsl:template match="*[*]" mode="outer">
<xsl:param name="key" as="xs:string?"/>
<xsl:variable name="distinctChildNames" as="xs:string*" select="*!name() => distinct-values()"/>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="count($distinctChildNames) gt 1 and exists($key)">
    <array>
      <xsl:sequence select="fn:keyAttribute(name())"/>
      <map>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="outer">
          <xsl:with-param name="key" select="name()"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </map>
    </array>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="count(*) gt 1 and count($distinctChildNames) eq 1">
    <map>
      <xsl:sequence select="fn:keyAttribute(name())"/>
      <array key="{name(*[1])}">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
          <map>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="outer"/>
          </map>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </array>
    </map>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <map>
      <xsl:sequence select="fn:keyAttribute(name())"/>      
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="outer">
        <xsl:with-param name="key" select="name()"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>  
    </map>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

The JSON output:

```json
    {
    "ClientID": "1",
    "PackageID": "650",
    "SBUID": "2187",
    "CandidateID": "456",
    "AssociateId": "789",
    "FirstName": "Meghana",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "Rao",
    "FatherName": "Satish",
    "ContactNo": "7530001169",
    "EmailID": "dummy@sap.com",
    "AddressHistory": {
        "Address": [
            {
                "SequenceNo": "0",
                "AddressLine": "Kharghar,navi mumbai",
                "City": "Maharashtra-Mumbai",
                "State": "Maharashtra",
                "PinCode": "410210",
                "Country": "India",
                "Landmark": "",
                "StayFrom": "01-08-2013",
                "StayTo": "06-08-2021",
                "IsCurrentAddress": false,
                "IsPermanentAddress": false,
                "HouseNo": "",
                "AddressType": "Current",
                "DocList": {
                    "listofdocs": [
                        {
                            "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
                            "DocumentPath": "base64"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "EducationList": {
        "Education": [
            {
                "SequenceNo": "0",
                "Qualification": "",
                "Degree": "Under Graduate Degree",
                "CollegeName": "Amrutvahini College of engineering, Sangamner (Pune University)",
                "Location": "",
                "RollNumber": "123123",
                "UniversityName": "Mumbai University",
                "UniversityAddress": "",
                "PeriodFrom": "",
                "PeriodTo": "",
                "YearOfPassing": "2014",
                "Zipcode": "",
                "Percentage": "",
                "AdditionalRemarks": "10th\/12th\/Undergrad etc",
                "International": false,
                "Country": "",
                "DocList": {
                    "listofdocs": [
                        {
                            "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
                            "DocumentPath": "base64"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "EmploymentList": {
        "Employment": [
            {
                "SequenceNo": "0",
                "EmployerName": "Stravis Solutions",
                "EmployerAddress": "Bangalore",
                "EmployerContactNo": "",
                "Designation": "SDE",
                "EmployeeID": "asdas",
                "FixedSalary": "0",
                "IsCurrentEmployment": false,
                "RelievingDate": "15-10-2021",
                "State": "",
                "City": "",
                "Zipcode": "",
                "International": false,
                "Country": "",
                "PFNumber": "",
                "UANNumber": "",
                "DocList": {
                    "listofdocs": [
                        {
                            "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
                            "DocumentPath": "base64"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "DateOfJoining": "18-03-2015"
            },
            {
                "SequenceNo": "0",
                "EmployerName": "Stravis Solutions",
                "EmployerAddress": "Bangalore",
                "EmployerContactNo": "",
                "Designation": "SDE",
                "EmployeeID": "asdas",
                "FixedSalary": "0",
                "IsCurrentEmployment": false,
                "RelievingDate": "15-10-2021",
                "International": false,
                "Country": "",
                "PFNumber": "",
                "UANNumber": "",
                "DocList": {
                    "listofdocs": [
                        {
                            "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
                            "DocumentPath": "base64"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "DateOfJoining": "18-03-2015"
            }
        ]
    },
    "AddressReferencesList": {
        "ListofReferences": [
            {
                "OrganizationName": "Com 1",
                "AdditionalRemarks": "",
                "NameOfReferee": "Ref1",
                "RefereeOccupation": "SDE",
                "RefereePhoneNumber": "123456",
                "RefereeEmailAddress": "Ref1@com1.com"
            },
            {
                "OrganizationName": "Com 1",
                "AdditionalRemarks": "",
                "NameOfReferee": "Ref1",
                "RefereeOccupation": "SDE",
                "RefereePhoneNumber": "123456",
                "RefereeEmailAddress": "Ref1@com1.com"
            }
        ]
    },
    "DOB": "03-08-2021",
    "DLDetails": {
        "DOB": "03-08-2021",
        "ApplicantName": "Test",
        "FatherName": "Test",
        "dl_remarks": "",
        "UniqueIDCode": "1231231",
        "DocList": {
            "listofdocs": [
                {
                    "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
                    "DocumentPath": "base64"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "PanDetails": {
        "DOB": "03-08-2021",
        "ApplicantName": "Sunil Kumar  Yadav",
        "FatherName": "Sunil",
        "pan_remarks": "",
        "UniqueIDCode": "23123131",
        "DocList": {
            "listofdocs": [
                {
                    "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
                    "DocumentPath": "base64"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "PVWDetails": {
        "AddressList": {
            "Address": [
                {
                    "SequenceNo": "0",
                    "AddressLine": "Kharghar,navi mumbai",
                    "City": "Maharashtra-Mumbai",
                    "State": "Maharashtra",
                    "PinCode": "410210",
                    "Country": "India",
                    "Landmark": "",
                    "StayFrom": "01-08-2013",
                    "StayTo": "06-08-2021",
                    "IsCurrentAddress": false,
                    "IsPermanentAddress": false,
                    "HouseNo": "Sai shradha CHS.Sector-11,",
                    "AddressType": "Current",
                    "DocList": {
                        "listofdocs": [
                            {
                                "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
                                "DocumentPath": "base64"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "DOB": "03-08-2021",
        "FatherName": "Sunil",
        "ApplicantName": "Sunil Kumar  Yadav"
    },
    "CreditDetail": {
        "ApplicantName": "Test",
        "DOB": "03-08-2021",
        "FatherName": "Test",
        "Gender": "Male",
        "UniqueIDCode": "Pan Number",
        "EmailID": "asda@gmail.com",
        "DocList": {
            "listofdocs": [
                {
                    "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
                    "DocumentPath": "base64"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "DrugTestPanelCheck": {
        "DrugTestPanel": "DrugTestPanel5",
        "ApplicantName": "Test Candidate"
    },
    "GDCDetails": {
        "ApplicantName": "Sunil Kumar  Yadav",
        "DOB": "03-08-2021",
        "FatherName": "Sunil"
    },
    "PassportCheckDetails": {
        "NameInPassport": "Sunil Kumar  Yadav",
        "PassportNo": "1231231",
        "MachineReadableZone": "",
        "CandidateFirstName": "Sunil",
        "CandidateLastName": "Yadav",
        "DOB": "03-08-2021",
        "FatherName": "Sunil",
        "DocList": {
            "listofdocs": [
                {
                    "DocumentName": "abc.jpg",
                    "DocumentPath": "base64"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

There are minor differences in the result:

1. The '/' character is escaped to `\/` in the JSON output
2. JSON properties transformed from empty XML elements: the XSLT here always keeps the property and sets the value to an empty string

Here's the full XSLT used:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:fn="com.example.functions"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
                expand-text="yes"
                version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:mode name="outer" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:variable name="result" as="node()*">
      <map>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="outer"/>
      </map>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:sequence select="xml-to-json($result)"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[*]" mode="outer">
    <xsl:param name="key" as="xs:string?"/>
    <xsl:variable name="distinctChildNames" as="xs:string*" select="*!name() => distinct-values()"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="count($distinctChildNames) gt 1 and exists($key)">
        <array>
          <xsl:sequence select="fn:keyAttribute(name())"/>
          <map>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="outer">
              <xsl:with-param name="key" select="name()"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
          </map>
        </array>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="count(*) gt 1 and count($distinctChildNames) eq 1">
        <map>
          <xsl:sequence select="fn:keyAttribute(name())"/>
          <array key="{name(*[1])}">
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
              <map>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="outer"/>
              </map>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </array>
        </map>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <map>
          <xsl:sequence select="fn:keyAttribute(name())"/>      
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="outer">
            <xsl:with-param name="key" select="name()"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>  
        </map>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[empty(*) and exists(text())]" mode="outer">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="outer">
      <xsl:with-param name="key" select="name()"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[empty(*) and empty(text())]" mode="outer">
    <string key="{name()}"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="text()[. = ('true', 'false')]" mode="outer">
    <xsl:param name="key" as="xs:string?"/>
    <boolean key="{$key}">{.}</boolean>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="text()" mode="outer">
    <xsl:param name="key" as="xs:string?"/>
    <xsl:if test="exists($key)">
      <string key="{$key}">{.}</string>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:function name="fn:keyAttribute" as="attribute()?">
    <xsl:param name="key" as="xs:string?"/>
    <xsl:if test="$key">
      <xsl:attribute name="key" select="$key"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:function>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```